# SELECT from table AND 'archive' table at once

Tags: mysql, sql

To reduce the size of one of our tables (currently over 4 million rows), I've created an 'archive' table which will only be accessed by certain users.

The archive table is a replica of the main table, except it has OLD rows in it that are rarely accessed.

However, sometimes I'll need to query both tables:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    t6.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT up.lesson_id) AS assessment_count, 
        MIN(up.date) AS first_date, 
        MAX(up.date) AS last_date
    FROM 
        cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE 
        (up.game_id = '0') AND 
        (up.uid = '150') AND 
        (up.lesson_id IN  ('65', '1112', '66', '67', '68', '69', '1114', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '1113', '77', '424', '423', '1115', '93', '94', '95', '420', '421', '422', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '1015', '102', '415', '104', '106', '105', '107', '108', '1016', '109', '110', '160', '111', '113', '112', '738', '739', '1050', '1051', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '1017', '123', '124', '125', '130', '1018', '131', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '267', '268', '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '1019', '278', '775', '279', '280', '281', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '1161', '287', '288', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293', '294', '295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '301', '318', '319', '302', '303', '304', '305', '306', '307', '308', '309', '337', '338', '339', '340', '341', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '1054', '347', '348', '349', '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '377', '378', '379', '380', '479', '480', '481', '482', '431', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437', '438', '439', '440', '441', '442', '443', '444', '445', '446', '448', '447', '449', '450', '451', '452', '453', '454', '456', '455', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '465', '466', '467', '468', '469', '470', '471', '472', '473', '474', '475', '476', '477', '478', '1090')) AND 
        (up.score > '-1')
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        AVG(c1.score) AS avg_first_scores, 
        SUM(c1.score) AS sum_first_scores
    FROM 
        cdu_user_progress c1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdu_user_progress c2 ON c1.uid = c2.uid AND c1.lesson_id = c2.lesson_id AND c1.game_id = c2.game_id AND c1.level = c2.level AND c1.date > c2.date AND c2.score > -1
    WHERE  
        (c1.game_id = '0') AND 
        (c1.uid = '150') AND 
        (c1.lesson_id IN  ('65', '1112', '66', '67', '68', '69', '1114', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '1113', '77', '424', '423', '1115', '93', '94', '95', '420', '421', '422', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '1015', '102', '415', '104', '106', '105', '107', '108', '1016', '109', '110', '160', '111', '113', '112', '738', '739', '1050', '1051', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '1017', '123', '124', '125', '130', '1018', '131', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '267', '268', '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '1019', '278', '775', '279', '280', '281', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '1161', '287', '288', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293', '294', '295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '301', '318', '319', '302', '303', '304', '305', '306', '307', '308', '309', '337', '338', '339', '340', '341', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '1054', '347', '348', '349', '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '377', '378', '379', '380', '479', '480', '481', '482', '431', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437', '438', '439', '440', '441', '442', '443', '444', '445', '446', '448', '447', '449', '450', '451', '452', '453', '454', '456', '455', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '465', '466', '467', '468', '469', '470', '471', '472', '473', '474', '475', '476', '477', '478', '1090')) AND 
        (c1.score > '-1') AND 
        (c2.date IS '')  
) t6
```

The solutions I've already thought of - replace `SELECT cdu_user_progress` with a nested-query:

```
SELECT * FROM cdu_user_progress UNION SELECT * FROM cdu_user_progress_archive
```

But this would create a huge temporary table in memory.

I tried UNION of each query (nested queries above), but this results in multiple rows returned, where it used to return a single row.

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM 
        cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE 
        ...
    UNION SELECT 
        ...
    FROM 
        cdu_user_progress_archive up
    WHERE 
        ...
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM 
        cdu_user_progress c1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdu_user_progress c2 ON c1.uid = c2.uid AND c1.lesson_id = c2.lesson_id AND c1.game_id = c2.game_id AND c1.level = c2.level AND c1.date > c2.date AND c2.score > -1
    WHERE  
        ...
    UNION SELECT 
        ...
    FROM 
        cdu_user_progress_archive c1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdu_user_progress_archive c2 ON c1.uid = c2.uid AND c1.lesson_id = c2.lesson_id AND c1.game_id = c2.game_id AND c1.level = c2.level AND c1.date > c2.date AND c2.score > -1
    WHERE  
        ...
) t6
```

Any other ideas???

Thanks!

Comment: 4 million rows isn't a lot of data by modern standards. Are you sure the archive table is worth it given the exponential increase in complexity here?

Comment: See about partitioning (by range).

Answer (score 0):

Those suq-queries contain aggregates.

So a simple solution is to sin against the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself).
I.e. copy&paste those queries, change to the archive tables and union them.

But that list of lesson_id's is rather long.
Probably better to put those in a temp table so it can be reused.

```
SELECT t1.*, t6.*
FROM (
    SELECT 'current' as Src,
     COUNT(DISTINCT up.lesson_id) AS assessment_count, 
     MIN(up.date) AS first_date, 
     MAX(up.date) AS last_date
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    INNER JOIN temp_lessonid_list lst
      ON lst.lesson_id = up.lesson_id
    WHERE up.game_id = 0 
    AND up.uid = 150 
    AND up.score > -1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'archive' as Src,
     COUNT(DISTINCT up.lesson_id) AS assessment_count, 
     MIN(up.date) AS first_date, 
     MAX(up.date) AS last_date
    FROM cdu_user_progress_archive up
    INNER JOIN temp_lessonid_list lst
      ON lst.lesson_id = up.lesson_id
    WHERE up.game_id = 0 
    AND up.uid = 150 
    AND up.score > -1
) t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 'current' as Src,
     AVG(c1.score) AS avg_first_scores, 
     SUM(c1.score) AS sum_first_scores
    FROM cdu_user_progress c1
    INNER JOIN temp_lessonid_list lst
      ON lst.lesson_id = c1.lesson_id
    LEFT JOIN cdu_user_progress c2 
      ON (c1.uid = c2.uid AND c1.lesson_id = c2.lesson_id AND c1.game_id = c2.game_id AND c1.level = c2.level AND c1.date > c2.date AND c2.score > -1)
    WHERE c1.game_id = 0
       AND c1.uid = 150
       AND c1.score > -1
       AND c2.date IS ''

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'archive' as Src,
     AVG(c1.score) AS avg_first_scores, 
     SUM(c1.score) AS sum_first_scores
    FROM cdu_user_progress_archive c1
    INNER JOIN temp_lessonid_list lst
      ON lst.lesson_id = c1.lesson_id
    LEFT JOIN cdu_user_progress_archive c2 
      ON (c1.uid = c2.uid AND c1.lesson_id = c2.lesson_id AND c1.game_id = c2.game_id AND c1.level = c2.level AND c1.date > c2.date AND c2.score > -1)
    WHERE c1.game_id = 0
       AND c1.uid = 150
       AND c1.score > -1
       AND c2.date IS ''
) t6 ON t6.Src = t1.Src;
```

You could also research table partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

you can write 2 separate queries for each table and use the mysql UNION keyword to join them together

eg

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col="value")
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE col="value");
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html